# Laptop crash when moving while on battery only

Tags: laptop, battery

My laptop is <2 years old. From some time, I have this problem. When it's on power, it works fine. It also works fine on the battery as long as I don't move it. As soon as I move it physically, it crashes.

Can anyone tell what's the problem and what should I do? I recently bought a new battery so I am sure battery is not the issue.

Comment: ***I recently bought a new battery so I am sure battery is not the issue***. That signals me the opposite... What happens if you use the old battery? Does it work?

Comment: @Andreas I bought a new battery because of the issue. The issue persisted even replacing the battery.

Comment: In that case my guess is that it's the pins on the laptop that had been bent. Try and bend out the pins and see if that helps

Comment: @Andreas If I bent, won't it damage it permanently?

Comment: Yes, bending pins can destroy the connector. Try "duct tape" to keep the battery from wobbling. If that helps, then you might try *gentle* realignment of the connector pins... or leave the tape, or replace it with a nice bumper sticker.

Comment: @varun well that depends on how you bend the pins. If you bend them back to the position they should be in, then it's not damaged, then it's fixed. But you could of course send it to a computer repair shop and they will probably do exactly that bend the pins slightly and charge you lots of money for it. But yes, there is a possibility that you damage the pins.

Comment: @Andreas Ah. Thank you. Now I understand what you mean. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you again. I did a few things. Bent the connectors gently, cleaned them with alcohol, and also stuffed some paper in the battery compartment to make it tighter.

I feel my PC is much more reliable today (~12 hours since). It crashed again today but not as often as yesterday. I just need to figure out whether it was alcohol or benting or paper which fixed it and do it better.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you again. I did a few things. Bent the connectors gently, cleaned them with alcohol, and also stuffed some paper in the battery compartment to make it tighter.

I feel my PC is much more reliable today (~12 hours since). It crashed again today but not as often as yesterday. I just need to figure out whether it was alcohol or benting or paper which fixed it and do it better.